# "I beg leave to assure you" — letter by John Marshall

Tags: verbs, meaning-in-context, word-usage

> Richmond May 1st [17]99 [(Source of Letter)](http://founders.archives.gov/?q=Author%3A%22Marshall%2C%20John%22&s=1111311111&r=18)
>
> Dear Sir
>
> You may possibly have seen a paragraph in a late publication, stating that several important offices in the gift of the Executive, & among others that of secretary of State, had been attainable by me. Few of the unpleasant occurrences produc’d by my declaration as a candidate for congress (& they have been very abundant) have given me more real chagrin than this. To make a parade of profferd offices is a vanity which I trust I do not possess, but to boast of one never in my power woud argue a littleness of mind at which I ought to blush.
>
> I know not how the author may have acquird his information, but I **beg leave** to assure you that he never receivd it directly nor indirectly from me. I had no previous knowledge that such a publication was designd, or I woud certainly have suppressd so much of it as relates to this subject.

Under Idioms, this page from the [Oxford Dictionary](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/beg) says:

> beg leave to do something (formal) = to ask somebody for permission to do something

Could someone please explicate and elucidate **beg leave**? I can't grasp how one would ask person X for permission to assure person X of something (particularly in this context). Wouldn't one just assure person X directly of whatever thing it is?

Comment: How do you feel about, "**let me** assure you that he never received..."?  This too asks for permission to assure before actually assuring.  A possible response, after all, might be, "I don't want your assurances."

Comment: @Jim: Many thanks. That helps. Please feel free to rewrite as an Answer for which I'll upvote.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**beg leave** simply means *I beg you to allow me to/give me permission to*

> I [**beg leave,**](http://books.google.com/books?id=YRMFAQAAIAAJ&pg=PR9&lpg=PR9&dq=etymology+%22beg+leave%22&source=bl&ots=0uqFKPJKfx&sig=y_14ByVnCXzN39LHT9EWhX9YCAY&hl=en&sa=X&ei=oH-3Uqv2LoLIsASWwoCADA&ved=0CE4Q6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=etymology%20%22beg%20leave%22&f=false) to repeat here, what I have already said in my former volume, that...

from **beg**

> ask formally for (permission to do something): I will now [**beg**](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/beg) to make some observations; from Old English bedecian, of Germanic origin; related to *bid*

and [**leave**](https://www.google.com/search?q=define+leave&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&aq=t&rls=org.mozilla%3aen-US%3aofficial&client=firefox-a)

> permission; from Old English *leaf*, meaning permission

Answer (score 3):

It is merely a polite and formal circumlocution. "Allow me to assure you.." is a similar phrase still in use (though that is so formal that it usually precedes something that the listener would not or could notr believe otherwise).